# Basic data binding in Go walk

Tags: data-binding, go

I am trying to understand how data binding works in Go [walk](https://godoc.org/github.com/lxn/walk).

I have reviewed the somewhat complex [data binding example](https://github.com/lxn/walk/blob/master/examples/databinding/databinding.go), but I am having difficulties implementing a simple, one field data binding.

The code below demonstrates more or less what I am trying to achieve - I want the text label to be bound to the `message` variable (i.e., to be synchronized with its content) - of course, without the need for me to push changes to the label itself.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/lxn/walk"
    . "github.com/lxn/walk/declarative"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var messageLabel *walk.Label
    var message string = "Hello"

    // Change `message` over 5 seconds
    go func() {
        for i := 1; i < 6; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            message = "Counting: " + strconv.Itoa(i)

            // I want to make it work
            // without this line below
            messageLabel.SetText(message)
        }
    }()

    // Build a simple window with a text label
    // that is supposed to be bound to the
    // contents of the `message` variable
    MainWindow{
        Title:   "Binding Test",
        MinSize: Size{300, 50},
        Layout:  VBox{},
        Children: []Widget{
            Label{
                AssignTo: &messageLabel,
                Text:     message,
                // Text:  BindTo{message} // Objective
            },
        },
    }.Run()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any Databinder code in your snapshot.

In that [exanple](https://github.com/lxn/walk/blob/master/examples/databinding/databinding.go) you mentioned,these code below makes databinding work

```
DataBinder: DataBinder{
            AssignTo:       &db,
            Name:           "animal",
            DataSource:     animal,
            ErrorPresenter: ToolTipErrorPresenter{},
        },
```

It binds the data who calls `Bind("Name")` to the field with the same name in `Datasource` which is `animal` in that example.